# How to auto select "select" option in html input after ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an AJAX request going to my PHP file to pull data from the database that pertains to the users. I want to autofill the form inputs. I was able to fill most of the inputs, but the HTML "select" option is really stumping me. Does anyone know how to autoselect the value in the database?
**HTML**

```
<select class="gender-reg" name="gender-reg">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    <option value="optout">Rather Not Say</option>
</select>
```

**AJAX REQUEST**

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8090/HELPERSITE/src/php/session.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $(".username-reg").attr("value", (response['username']));
            $(".pwd-reg").attr("value", (response['password']));
            $(".email-reg").attr("value", (response['email']));
            $(".acct-type").text(response['type']);
            $(".fname-reg").attr("value", (response['fname']));
            $(".lname-reg").attr("value", (response['lname']));

            $(".gender-reg").attr("value", (response['gender']));

            $(".street-reg").attr("value", (response['street']));

        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [**`.val()`**](https://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$(".gender-reg").val(response['gender']);
```

Comment: its .val() not .va() in your description.

Comment: wow thanks a lot! i didnt know it was the easy.... is there a list of all the jquery values of html elements you can manipulate?

Comment: @JamesBargon, you are most welcome, you can find the list of attributes in jQuery...https://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/